# pyproject.toml listing an editable package as a dependency for an editable package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

Using setuptools, is it possible to list another editable package as a dependency for an editable package?

I'm trying to develop a collection of packages in order to use them across different production services, one of these packages (`my_pkg_1`) depends on a subset of my package collection (`my_pkg_2`, `my_pkg_x`, ...), so far, I've managed to put together this `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_pkg_1"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [
    "my_pkg_2 @ file:///somewhere/in/mysystem/my_pkg_2"
]
```

which *does* work when/for installing `my_pkg_1` in editable mode, and it does install `my_pkg_2` but not in editable mode. this is what I see when I `pip list`:

```bash
Package         Version Editable project location
--------------- ------- -------------------------
my_pkg_2         0.0.1
my_pkg_1         0.0.1   /somewhere/in/mysystem/my_pkg_1
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? if so, how?

Comment: You probably should rather use a `requirements.txt` file for this instead.

Comment: @sinoroc, are you saying I can reference a requirements.txt file in the package's pyproject.toml?

Comment: No. I am saying this can not be done the way you want to do it (in the project's dependencies metadata). But you could do it with a `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

You may install my_pkg_2 explicitly in editable mode before installing my_pkg_1:

`pip install --editable /somewhere/in/mysystem/my_pkg_2`

Unfortunately, It is not possible to install dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies) automatically in editable mode by installing the main package. I am curious why it is not implemented.

Alternatively, you may add the package paths to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` before running code from your main package. That way, you are able to import python modules from your other packages without having to install them.

Comment: Yes, this was my "dirty fix"

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done in `pyproject.toml`. At least not the way you want it and in a standard way.

If I were you I would write for myself a `requirements.txt` file (you could also give it a different name, obviously):

```
# install the current project as editable
--editable .

# install `my_pk_2` as editable
--editable /somewhere/in/mysystem/my_pkg_2
```

And you could use it like so:

```
path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install --requirement 'path/to/requirements.txt'
```

for when you want to work on (edit) both pieces of software at the same time in the same environment.

Alternatively you could use a "development workflow tool" (such as PDM, Hatch, Poetry, and so on), and maybe one of those would be a better fit for your expectations.